# Why is solution to equation $z^2 = |z|^2, z \in \mathbb{C}$ equal to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve this equation via substitution $z = a + bi$, but it gives me wrong result. How can I generally, solve those kind of equations, where we have, for example both $|z|, |z+1|...$ and $z, z^2,...$ and so?

Comment: $z^2=(a+bi)^2$, while $|z|^2=a^2+b^2$.  Now equate the two...

Comment: If you've learned polar form, letting $z=re^{i\theta}$ would be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Writing $\;z=x+iy\;$ :

$$z^2=|z|^2\iff x^2-y^2+2xyi = x^2+y^2\iff$$

$$y^2-xyi=0\iff y=0$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y^2-xyi = 0$? And doesn't it also have solution $y = ix$?

Comment: Yes, it should be with minus...and no: a complex number vanishes iff its real and imaginary parts are zero.

Comment: From which we go $y(y-xi) = 0$ so it also has solution $y = xi$ right? Of course, per definition we should have $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. This is just important to remember.

Comment: @πr8 That's exactly what I'm saying. I'm simply trying to say that $y^2 - xyi = 0$ implies $y=0$ only because we have the assumption that $y$ must be real.

Comment: @Eff No: $\;y=xi\;$ cannot be **unless** both $\;x=y=0\;$ , as $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ ...and **of course** we have that assumption! If we write $\;z=x+iy\;$ and *we know* $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$ , then $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ , so $\;z=x\in\Bbb R\;$ and we're done.

Comment: It does not have to be "of course" from the point of view of a student just starting complex analysis (and this question is pretty basic). The fact that when we write $z = x + i y$ then $x,y$ is real is a **convention** that we all have learned at some point and it's so standard that we usually don't have to spell it out. Anyway it still have to be learned at one point so Eff's comment is valid.

Comment: @Kibble Of course, and I think it is important fro a beginner to understand why that "of course" is well placed. General and standard agreement on notation makes that clear, and students must understand this as soon as possible...and I think the OP does.

Answer (score 2):

$$z^2=|z|^2\iff z^2-|z|^2=0\iff z^2-z\bar{z}=0\iff z(z-\bar{z})=0\iff z=\bar{z}$$

Note that $z=\bar{z}\iff z\in\mathbb{R}$, so the equation is satisfied precisely when $z$ is real.

Answer (score 1):

As for the given equation, putting as you did $z=a+ib $, you obtain the equation
$$
a^2+2iab-b^2=a^2+b^2.
$$
Then you conclude that
$$
ab=0,\quad \textrm{and} \quad a^2-b^2=a^2+b^2,
$$
hence b=0.
This is the result. What did you obtained?

Comment: I've obtained $b^2 - abi = 0$, but I haven't realised, that $b$ has to be $0$, for this equation to be true, and hence $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Of course your equation is correct and you only needed to do the final step